# add code on specific category id opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: opencart2.3

I want to add a image with a link on a specific category id but can't seem to work out how to do it in category.tpl file, below is what I have but nothing is showing on the category

```
<?php if($category_id=="1697") { ?>
        <a href="#"><img alt="Seagate Barracuda SSD's" class="img-responsive" src="image/catalog/Seagate-Barracuda-SSDs.jpg" /></a>
    <?php } ?>
```

I am using seo urls but thought as it's the category id, it would show or is there something I need to add into the catalog.php controller file?

Update: Just managed to solve it with the following code

In catalog/controller/product/catalog.php, added the following in

```
$data['category_id'] = $category_id;
```

In catalog/view/theme/default/product/catalog.tpl, I got the following

```
<?php if ($category_id == '1697') { ?>
       <a href="#"><img alt="Seagate Barracuda SSD's" class="img-responsive" src="image/catalog/Seagate-Barracuda-SSDs.jpg" /></a>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First in the default OC in folder `catalog/view/theme/default/product` file catalog.tpl does not exist and `catalog.php` in the corresponding controller folder also does not exist.

Maybe you want to retrieve in `catalog/view/theme/default/product/category.tpl`?
So if you want to retrieve `category_id` in `catalog/view/theme/default/product/category.tpl` you should:

in `catalog/controller/product/category.php`
find:

```
$category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);
```

belowe add:

```
$data['category_id'] = $category_info['category_id'];
```

Now you can in `catalog/view/theme/default/product/category.tpl` use your code:

```
<?php if ($category_id == '1697') { ?>
       <a href="#"><img alt="Seagate Barracuda SSD's" class="img-responsive" src="image/catalog/Seagate-Barracuda-SSDs.jpg" /></a>
    <?php } ?>
```